# Rails - Tracking non-logged in user activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Say an application has many Products and searching capabilities. 
1. How can I track page views on each product(a simple counter) and
2. how can I track search queries as well?

Most importantly, I need to be able to find/order products by number of page views.

The (simpler / best performance / least outside dependency)  the better!

Why this question? The solutions I've seen so far are either out of date gems or don't work well with searching.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it. In the model:

```
def increment(by = 1)
  self.views ||= 0 #Prevents error if views can be nil
  self.views += by
  self.save
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
@model.increment
```

Faster if made into an asynchronous job which I still need to do.

To prevent users spamming refresh or something I made it a bit more complicated:

```
  def show
    product_itemcode = params[:itemcode]
    @product = Product.find_by(itemcode: product_itemcode)

    unless session[product_itemcode.to_s]
      @product.increment
      session[product_itemcode.to_s] = true
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

An increment method already exists:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment

You still have to call object.save though